# How to return FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, generics, ienumerable

I have method where I want to return only one record, but I can't use `FirstOrDefault`. The connection with database works fine, I already tried.

I want to find record passing some values.

This is what I tried:

```
public async Task<CorridoioWebResponse> GetCorridoiWeb_ID(string stab, string maga, string area, Int32 cors)
{
    string strsql = string.Empty;
    string strErrore = string.Empty;
    string strConnessione = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnDB");
    SqlServerCompiler compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
    CorridoioWebResponse coridoio;
    using (IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnessione))
    {
        using (var db = new QueryFactory(cn, compiler))
        {
            strsql = "SELECT * from tmhit.CORRIDOI_CORSIE WHERE STAB=" + stab + "AND MAGA =" + maga + "AND AREA=" + area + "AND CORS=" + cors;
            //strsql = "SELECT top 1 STAB, MAGA, AREA, CORS from tmhit.CORRIDOI_CORSIE WHERE STAB=" + stab + "AND MAGA =" + maga + "AND AREA=" + area + "AND CORS=" + cors;
            //SELECT top 1 STAB, MAGA, AREA, CORS from tmhit.CORRIDOI_CORSIE WHERE STAB = 1 and MAGA = 0 and AREA = 0 and CORS = 9
            var _corridoio = await cn.QueryAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(strsql);
            if (_corridoio.Count() == 0)
                throw new ToyotaException("Non ci sono corridoi mappati");

            coridoio = _corridoio;
        }
    }

    return coridoio;
}
```

Model:

```
public class CorridoioWebResponse
{
    public string stab { get; set; }
    public string maga { get; set; }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public Int32 cors { get; set; }
}
```

The error that it gives me:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ModelSOme.Model_WebInterface.Mapatura.CorridoioWebResponse>' to
> 'ModelSomeModel_WebInterface.Mapatura.CorridoioWebResponse'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that `await cn.QueryAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(strsql)` returns `IEnumerable<CorridoioWebResponse>` and you are trying to assign it to `CorridoioWebResponse coridoio` and get type mismatch error.

Try something like this: `coridoio = _corridoio.FirstOrDefault();` (don't forget to `using System.Linq`)

Comment: [QueryFirstAsync<T>](https://dapper-tutorial.net/async#queryfirstasync) or [QuerySingleAsync<T>](https://dapper-tutorial.net/async#querysingleasync) could also be used

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with this code - string concatenation to generate the query and returning the `IEnumerable<>` results when the method returns only a single item.

Right now, you get a compilation error. Even if it's fixed, you'll get *runtime* errors as text values get injected into the query. The substrings have no spaces around them so the entire WHERE clause will be invalid : `WHERE STAB=123AND MAGA =345AND CORS=abc`

Replace the code with this :

```
var strsql = "SELECT TOP 1 * from tmhit.CORRIDOI_CORSIE WHERE STAB=@stab AND MAGA=@maga AND AREA=@area AND CORS=@cors";
var _corridoio = await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(
                           strsql, 
                           new {stab,maga,area,cors});
```

This will pass the parameter values by name and return the first result

Answer (score 0):

I see the errors:

**ModelSOme.Model_WebInterface** is difference **ModelSomeModel_WebInterface**

You see "." at between S0me.Model and _corridoio, It is a list, I thought

You should using same model.

Comment: I just created new model and I allways use the same model. I update my question with model code

Answer (score 0):

Seems like more of a SQL problem instead of a C# one.

Try this one:

```sql
    SELECT Top 1 * from tmhit.CORRIDOI_CORSIE WHERE STAB=.....
```

EDIT:

change this:

```cs
    var _corridoio = await cn.QueryAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(strsql);
```

to this:

```cs
    var _corridoioList = await cn.QueryAsync<IEnumerable<CorridoioWebResponse>>(strsql);
    
    var _corridoio = _corridoioList.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: What makes this so? SQL doesn't use classes or interfaces, it simply returns a table of data. The problem is as gyromonotron has pointed out in his answer, `QueryAsync` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @kvacka: i updated my answer. Also, if you are just interested in the first result you should update your sql to TOP, so you will get less data.

Answer (score 0):

`await cn.QueryAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(strsql)` always returns a `IEnumerable`, because `QueryAsync` is relational with SQL table, Think that, SQL tables are like an `IEnumerable` list.

Your object's (`coridoio`) type should be `IEnumerable<CorridoioWebResponse>` and then you can use `coridoio.FirstOrDefault()` and return this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `FirstOrDefault()` then use `ToList()`:

```
var _corridoio = (await cn.QueryAsync<CorridoioWebResponse>(strsql)).ToList();
if (_corridoio.Count == 0)
    throw new ToyotaException("Non ci sono corridoi mappati");

coridoio = _corridoio[0];
```